# How to track when email is categorized?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

We are using Outlook as a main tool for daily work.

It starts when employee assigns a category to mail and ends when this mail is sent.

I would like to extract when mail was categorized (date and hour, name of category) when it was sent and subject of this mail, to an Excel worksheet.

I plan to add such a macro into ThisOutlookSession. I have no idea how to extract category events from Outlook.

I've been able extract only when email was sent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the [PropertyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.propertychange) event which is fired when an explicit built-in property (for example, [Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.categories)) of the object is changed. The name of the property that was changed is passed as a parameter to the event handler. For example, a raw sketch:

```
 Private WithEvents olExplorer As Outlook.Explorer
 Private olCurSel As Selection
 Private WithEvents olCurSelItem As Outlook.MailItem

 Private Sub olExplorer_SelectionChange()
  Set olCurSel = olExplorer.Selection
  Set olCurSelItem = Nothing
   If TypeName(olCurSel.Item(1)) = "MailItem" Then
    Set olCurSelItem = olCurSel.Item(i)
   End If
 End Sub

 Private Sub olCurSelItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
  Debug.Print Name
 End Sub
```